# How to update top n rows dynamically?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with similar rows...like

```
PartNo  SerialNo  Inven_Qty  Status
------  --------  ---------  ------
001A    NULL      1          IN
001A    NULL      1          IN
001A    NULL      1          IN
001A    NULL      1          IN
```

Now I want to update the rows dynamically..I have a web page where I enter PartNo and the value of items which are OUT...ex 2 items are OUT...I want to update 2 rows with Inven_Qty 0 and status as OUT....Can anyone please tell me how to do this???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an id column on this table?

Comment: Please explain your situation more clearly. What do you WANT to achieve? I believe you are doing something wrong with the current explanation you have provided. I think your requirements can be met more elegantly. Please provide requirement.

Comment: No, There is no ID column in my table.

Comment: I have the above table with ex.4 records, if I enter PartNo 001A and Value 3 in a jsp page ..then only 3 rows should update as Status =OUT,Inv_qty =0.

Answer (score 13):

Based on Mikael Eriksson, for Oracle:

```
update YourTable
  set Inven_Qty = 0,
      Status = 'OUT'
where PartNo = '001A'
  and Status = 'IN'
  and rownum<=3
```

(for 3 items to update)

Comment: Thanks alot ...This query is working fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Clean and simple.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax works for SQL Server. Might work for other DBMS as well.

```
update top (2) YourTable
set Inven_Qty = 0,
    Status = 'OUT'
where PartNo = '001A' and
      Status = 'IN'
```

Another way that may be more easily translated to a some other DBMS

```
with C as
(
  select Inven_Qty,
         Status,
         row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as rn
  from @T
  where PartNo = '001A' and
        Status = 'IN'
)
update C
set Inven_Qty = 0,
    Status = 'OUT'
where rn <= 2
```

Comment: with first query am getting ORA-00971: missing SET keyword error. second one bit confusing where to give the Value?

Comment: @sailaja - That means that you are using Oracle. The value controlling the number of rows to update is here `where rn <= 2`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Status = "OUT", Invent_QTY = 0,
WHERE PartNo = "<part number>" AND SerialNo = <serial number>
```

Comment: So if you enter a particular part number, it should update all entries with that part number? or is there a particular criteria?

Comment: No, I only enter PartNo and Value ..for ex my table have 10 records....with status IN, when I enter Value as 4 its shd update only 4 rows status as OUT, and 6rows status shd be IN.Please help me out.

Comment: WHERE PartNo = "<part number>" AND rownum < <value> 
This might work in oracle.

Answer (score -1):

It would probably be better if you could use 'SerialNo' in the query, but if not you can try:

```
update <your table> set Status='OUT', Inven_Qty=0 where rowid in 
    (select rowid from <your table> where Status=IN and Inven_Qty=1
        and PartNo=<part number> where rownum <= <some value>)
```

But this only works if you assume that Inven_Qty is either 1 or 0. If Inven_Qty can be greater than 1 I don't think you can even do this with just a single query.

EDIT: This won't work if SerialNo is null. You have to have some sort of unique id for this to work. If you don't you should add one. If you're working on oracle you can use ROWID.

Comment: The Inven_Qty is always 1 or 0 not more than that...Thanks alot for the answer. Will try this.

Comment: This query gives some ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error. I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: LIMIT is not valid syntax in Oracle.